# Invalid FromUrl error when submitting job

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm getting this error:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training testX 
    --job-dir="gs://testxxx"
    --package-path=trainer
    --module-name=trainer.task
    --region us-central1

ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) 
argument --job-dir: invalid FromUrl value: 'gs://testxxx'
```

However, if I submit it at staging:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training testX 
    --staging-bucket="gs://testxxx"
    --package-path=trainer
    --module-name=trainer.task
    --region us-central1
```

It works just fine ... Any clue of why this error is showing?

Thanks!

M

Comment: This looks like a bug. We will investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `gcloud` expects `--job-dir` to be an object path (not a bucket). So try something like `--job-dir="gs://testxxx/run1`.

In the meantime, we will improve the error message; we will consider allowing buckets to be used as the actual `job-dir` as well.

Comment: I'm trying to run it locally, using `gcloud ml-engine local train` and I'm still getting the same error `ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.train) argument --job-dir: invalid FromUrl value:`. Could you please let me know why would this happen? I'm providing a local directory path to `--job-dir`

Comment: We will investigate the issue with local paths and get back to you.

Comment: This fix will appear in a future release of gcloud within the next couple of weeks.